# superclass reference to subclass object

Tags: c++, inheritance, point-cloud-library

I am trying to overwrite a class with my own version and then create a superclass reference to that class but I am getting a compile error.  Here is my code structure

File: RailExtractionInteractorStyle.h  (This is my subclass which inherits the super class PCLVisualizerInteractor)

```
#include<pcl/visualization/interactor_style.h>


class RailExtractionInteractorStyle : public pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle
{
public:
    RailExtractionInteractorStyle();
};
```

File: RailExtractionInteractor.cpp:

```
#include "RailExtractionInteractorStyle.h"

RailExtractionInteractorStyle::RailExtractionInteractorStyle()
    : pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle()
{
    // just calling super constructor for now
}
```

File: CloudPointPicker.hpp (An arbitrary class that uses RailExtractionInteractorStyle class)

```
#include "RailExtractionInteractorStyle.h"

template <typename PointT>
class CloudPointPicker {

protected:


    PointCloudTConstPtr cloud_;
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> myview_;


    //attempting to write my own interactor
    RailExtractionInteractorStyle* mystyle_;

public:

    CloudPointPicker() {
        *mystyle_ = new RailExtractionInteractorStyle;

    }
```

The statement in the CloudPointPicker constructor is giving me the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*((CloudPointPicker<pcl::PointXYZ>*)this)->CloudPointPicker<pcl::PointXYZ>::mystyle_ = (operator new(480u), (<statement>, ((RailExtractionInteractorStyle*)<anonymous>)))’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is that error message pointing to?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think the `*mystyle_ = new RailExtractionInteractorStyle;` line on constructor.

Comment: Are you trying to do `*mystyle_ = ...` on an uninitialized pointer? Didn't we covered that in another of your questions?

Comment: yes, it is the statement in the cloudPointPicker constructor as mentioned in the question.  I don't think this was covered in another one of of my questions.  That one was a template issue.  I am actually trying to initialize mystyle_ in this statement.  Is that not the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the * at the beginning of this line:

```
*mystyle_ = new RailExtractionInteractorStyle;
```

The operator new apply to the pointer directly, you don't need to dereference it.

Comment: I get the following two errors when removing the star:             `undefined reference to RailExtractionInteractorStyle::RailExtractionInteractorStyle()` and
                                                                `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Did you write the implementation of the function RailExtractionInteractorStyle::RailExtractionInteractorStyle() somewhere ? It seems the first error message you got is complaining that your compiler can not find the implementation.